# Is Auto Post recognition a WordPress feature? How to turn it off?

Tags: php, redirect

I noticed that if you go to [lostlettermen.com/aa](http://lostlettermen.com/aa), it redirects to a post.  Is this a feature in WordPress that can be turned off, or is this done by some type of plugin or custom code?

Comment: custom code query

Answer (score 3):

This is done by [`redirect_guess_404_permalink()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.3/wp-includes/canonical.php#L381), which [is called from `redirect_canonical()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.3/wp-includes/canonical.php#L83). `redirect_canonical()` does more than just this: it makes sure you are always using a single canonical URL for an item, it will add slashes, force the same domain name, ...

You can either unhook `redirect_canoncial` so it does nothing, or you can hook into it and prevent redirection when it is a 404:

```
// Disable redirect_canonical()
add_action( 'init', 'wpse18110_init' );
function wpse18110_init()
{
    remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );
}

// Only prevent redirect on 404
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', 'wpse18110_redirect_canonical' );
function wpse18110_redirect_canonical( $redirect_url )
{
    if ( is_404() ) {
        return false;
    }
    return $redirect_url;
}
```

Comment: nice! didn't know about the redirect_guess_404_permalink()