# Prevent Wordpress from automatically correcting URLs

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, htaccess

I notice that if I type in `http://www.example.com/pag` I can land on an existing page that has a name like `http://www.example.com/page_five`. I don't know exactly what causes this, but I want to know if there is a way to stop it from happening.

Comment: [duplicate question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18110/is-auto-post-recognition-a-wordpress-feature-how-to-turn-it-off/)

Answer (score 2):

This happens in [`redirect_canonical()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.5.1/wp-includes/canonical.php#L39).

You can disable that function with:

```
remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

But be aware it does a lot more. Too much for my taste …
So there might be side effects.

Comment: What else does it do? I did a quick search and I couldn't find any documentation.

Comment: @Emerson I made an update to my answer and added a link to the function’s source code. It is really, really long.