# How to turn off searching from URL and go straight to 404 page

Tags: url-rewriting, search

When I put something after my domain name that doesn't exist I am taken to my 404 page, for example:

```
example.com/sdkjhfdsjk
```

But if I put something that exists as an image I am taken to the page for that, for example:

example.com/imagename

How can I turn this off. I only want to be taken to pages or posts that exist.

UPDATE: This has been [marked as a duplicate](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96905/prevent-wordpress-from-automatically-correcting-urls) but the accepted answer to that does NOT fix this.

I added:

```
remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

to my themes `functions.php` but the same action happens.

Comment: Are you talking about images in the media library?

Comment: Yes, images in the media library.

Comment: does it go to an image or to attachment page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
function no_attachment_page() {
  global $wp_query;
  if ( $wp_query->is_attachment()  ) {
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header(404);
    nocache_headers();
  }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'no_attachment_page', 1 );
```

This should result in a 404 everytime you try to access to an attachment page.